# Continuity of Electric Field Lines

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields

My textbook exercise asks the question

> "Electric field lines cannot be discontinuous. Explain."

I thought about something related to potential and stuff like that to somehow show that they cannot be discontinuous but I see no problem with that? Why can't potential not be defined at a point? Has it something to do with nature or what?

Comment: The electric field for a single point charge is discontinuous -- in fact singular -- at the point charge.

Comment: Electric field lines are discontinuous at the location of electric charges, but continuous otherwise.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [Why can't an electric field line suddenly break?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/579363/why-cant-an-electric-field-line-suddenly-break)

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I am confused by your comment. This question was asked Dec 30 2016 (almost four years ago). How can it be a duplicate of a question asked Sep 13 **this year** ? Finding it in the Close vote list looks like a mistake.

Comment: @GiorgioP Closing older questions as duplicates of newer ones is unusual, but it is [the standard policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147651/380389) in cases where the newer question is better. I'll leave it to the community to decide which is better- feel free to bring it up on meta if you disagree with the closure.

Comment: @Giorgio what Chris said.

Answer (score 2):

Electric field lines *can* be discontinuous. Consider an infinite sheet of uniform charge density. The field is constant on either side of the sheet, but abruptly switches direction when moving from one side to the other. The field is discontinuous at the location of the sheet.

A more proper statement would probably be: "If we only allow finite volumetric charge densities, electric field lines cannot be discontinuous."

Comment: The fact that the field is discontinuous does not imply that the field lines break - it implies that they have a kink, i.e., their derivative is discontinuous. This answer is completely incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Gauss's law says (in integral form) that
$$\oint \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{S} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon},$$
where $Q$ is the charge enclosed by the closed surface on the LHS.

This tells us that the net electric flux into or out of a volume depends on the net charge within it. If there is *no* charge, then the flux in equals the flux out.

A quantity of electric flux can be represented by a field line. If the net flux in/out of a volume is zero, then the number of field lines going in equals the number of field lines coming out. This will equally be true for any smaller subset of a chargeless volume, so the field lines are simply continuous.

Another way of expressing this is that electric field lines begin on positive charges and end on negative charges.

So your textbook must be talking about free space, or treating media as continuous with smooth, finite charge densities. This latter is an approximation, since in a polarisable medium there are both positive and negative charges and field lines should begin and end throughout the medium. In practice however, since we don't sketch a field line for every charge, it is is only discontinuities in charge per unit area that would result in field lines beginning, ending or abruptly changing direction (such as at the interface between media with different dielectric constants).

Comment: It's not just in free space that this is true, but in any space where you have a finite volumetric charge density. Only point charges and infinitely thin sheets of charge cause discontinuities.

Comment: Finite charge density is just a way of saying there are no discrete charges. This is an approximation, since ultimately all charges are point charges. You are just reiterating the point I made in my answer that in practice we "smooth" the charges in a polarisable medium and do not draw field lines at the level of individual charges. @probably_someone

Answer (score -1):

An electrostatic field line represents the actual path travelled by a unit positive charge in an electric field. If the line have sudden breaks it means the unit positive charge jumps from one place to another which is not possible. It also means that electric field becomes zero suddenly at the breaks which is not possible. So, the field line cannot have sudden breaks.

Comment: Are you trying to suggest that charged particles cannot move *across* electric field lines (along an equipotential surface for example)?