# Why can't an electric field line suddenly break?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, vector-fields

My book has the following question in it as an exercise:

> An electrostatic field line is a continuous curve i.e. a field line cannot have sudden breaks. Why not?

I cannot seem to be able to reason for or against this statement.

- Can somebody please tell me why they can't suddenly break and if that were to happen then what will be its outcome?

Comment: One could argue that [Schwinger production](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_effect) is an example of the breaking of electric field lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electric field lines have no physical existence: they are useful concepts to understand vector fields, but they do not carry an independent physical ontology of their own.

Given a vector field $\mathbf E(\mathbf r)$, we define the field lines as the solutions of the differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol \gamma}{\mathrm ds} = \mathbf E(\boldsymbol \gamma(s)),
\tag 1
$$
i.e., as the continuous curves whose derivative is given by the electric field at the curve. (This is up to re-parametrizations of the curve, which turn the equation above into a proportionality, but which don't affect the geometric locus of the field line, which is ultimately the only thing we care about.)

The definition $(1)$ means that field lines can have kinks where their derivative is discontinuous if they meet places where the electric field is discontinuous, such as at a surface charge.

However, field lines cannot break because we *define* them as continuous objects: basically, putting a pen at a starting point and then following the arrows of the vector field without lifting the pen.

Answer (score 2):

Charges are "sources" and "sinks" of electric field lines. If a field line was "broken" it would indicate the presence of a charge. If this were not the case then Gauss's law would not hold. Gauss's law guarantees continuous field lines except at the location of charges.

Comment: Can you please contrast the point made [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/301822/249968)  by the user @probably_someone with that of yours. Thanks!

Comment: @JohanLiebert The sheet has charges on it, so my answer is consistent with that answer. I'll edit to be more clear

Answer (score 0):

My answer is complementary to that given by @BioPhysicist, who looked at the problem from the point of view of the integral form of the Gauss law. Its differential form says:
$$
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0},
$$
which means the electric field has finite derivative everywhere except singular points/surfaces, which means that **the electric field itself continuous**, i.e. the electric field lines cannot interrupt. However **the derivative of electric field can experience jumps**, i.e. the electric field lines can be broken, but this requires singular charge distributions (point charges, charged wires of zero thickness or infinitely thin charged planes) or sharp material boundaries.

Comment: I think you meant complementary ("extending"/"detalizing") rather than complimentary ("praising").

Comment: Thanks  - I had never paid attention that they are spelled differently. I had a similar issue with career/carrier and discrete/discreet in the past :)

Answer (score 0):

Electric Fields, E are continuous gradients measured in volts/m [V/m] since this is due to the measurement of a voltage at a distance via the air medium which acts a variable attenuator according to geometry from a plate , line or point source that varies continuously by gap respectively as $$ k/r, k/r^2, k/r^3 $$

For a point source, attenuation results are defined by a Friis Loss formula for a defined source and receiver of measurement.

### Conclusion

In  order to have a discontinuity in E field , consider you need to have a discontinuity in space.