# Why can't electric field lines have discontinuities?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

My uni course notes says the following about a point charge in free space:

> ... in free space, $\nabla \cdot E = 0$, so there can be no discontinuities in the field lines generated by the charge.

I know that there have been other questions on here about why field lines are continuous so this may be a duplicate, but I haven't found an answer that I intuitively understand. Also, I specifically don't understand how the fact that $\nabla \cdot E = 0$ in free space relates to this continuity, and I haven't seen anyone ask that specific question.

Could anyone help me understand this?

Comment: More on [electric fields and continuity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Belectric-fields%5D+continu*).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't an electric field line suddenly break?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/579363/)

Comment: @Farcher I've read this post before and I understand it, but my main confusion is how ∇⋅ = 0 relates to this?

Comment: Well, of course, experimentally we don't always see $\nabla \cdot E = 0$. In essence, it's violations of this rule that we use to detect charge. There is no other definition of what charge is. So, if we have no charge, we have your "empty space".

This is all part of Maxwell's abstract model, which we use because it works for many other experiments, too. There is no other justification: physics is an experimental science.

Comment: If a vector field is differentiable(as implied by Maxwell's equations) then it must be continuous as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sufficient conditions for a 3D vector field $\mathbf F$ to be continuous are that both $\nabla\cdot\mathbf F$ and $\nabla\times\mathbf F$ are continuous.

This is because those expressions contain every partial derivative of every component of the field:

$\nabla\cdot\mathbf F = \partial_xF_x + \partial_yF_y + \partial_zF_z$

$(\nabla\times\mathbf F)_x = \partial_yF_z - \partial_zF_y$

$(\nabla\times\mathbf F)_y = \partial_zF_x - \partial_xF_z$

$(\nabla\times\mathbf F)_z = \partial_xF_y - \partial_yF_x$

If all 4 of these expressions are continuous then each component of $\mathbf F$ has continuous partial derivatives and therefore $\mathbf F$ itself is continuous.

For the electric field $\mathbf E$ Maxwell's equations state that $\nabla\cdot\mathbf E = \frac{\rho}{\varepsilon_0}$ and $\nabla\times\mathbf E = -\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}$. Specifically for your case of the electric field generated by a point charge (outside the point containing the charge) both the divergence and curl are $0$ which is continuous. Therefore the electric field is continuous.

Edit: My mistake, the statement refers to the electric field *lines* rather than the electric field itself.

As written in the answer to the linked duplicate post the field lines are the curves $\vec \gamma$ generated by using $\mathbf E$ as the velocity vector at each point:

$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d s} \vec\gamma(s) = \mathbf E(\vec\gamma(s))$

In general these curves are continuous wherever $\mathbf E$ is continuous.